# query left join doesn't return expected result

Tags: mysql, left-join

I have two query 
1) tree and 2) units

**first query**

```
SELECT * FROM tree WHERE entity_id = 8656
```

return below data:

```
entity id | parent_id | length
-------------------------------
8656      | 8656      | 0
8656      | 8655      | 1
8656      | 8654      | 2
8656      | 8653      | 3
8656      | 4331      | 4
8656      | 2         | 5
8656      | 1         | 6
```

**second query**

```
SELECT * FROM units WHERE activity_id =10066
```

returns

```
id  | activity_id | activity_name | region_id | region_name 
-----------------------------------------------------------
136 | 10066       | Cricket       | 4331      | Yote
137 | 10066       | Cricket       | 8653      | Handbreath
140 | 10066       | Cricket       | 8656      | Kevb
```

result expected

```
    entity id | parent_id | length | region_name
    --------------------------------------------
    8656      | 8656      | 0      | Kevb
    8656      | 8655      | 1      | null
    8656      | 8654      | 2      | null
    8656      | 8653      | 3      | Handbreath
    8656      | 4331      | 4      | Yote
    8656      | 2         | 5      | null
    8656      | 1         | 6      | null
```

I have tried this query

```
SELECT tree . * , units.region_name
FROM tree
LEFT JOIN units ON tree.parent_id = units.region_id
WHERE tree.entity_id = 8656
AND units.activity_id = 10066
```

Comment: Where is your query with the `LEFT JOIN` that doesn't return the expected result? post it please with the tables' structures.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By moving the `u.activity_id =10066` to the `LEFT JOIN` and not the `WHERE` clause, I am able to produce the result:

```
select t.entity_id,
  t.parent_id,
  t.length,
  u.region_name
from tree t
left join units u
  on t.parent_id = u.region_id
  and u.activity_id =10066
WHERE t.entity_id = 8656
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f1593/1)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT t.entity_id, t.arent_id, t.length, A.region_name
FROM tree t 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT region_id, region_name FROM units WHERE activity_id =10066 ) AS A ON t.arent_id = A.region_id 
WHERE entity_id = 8656
```

**OR**

```
SELECT t. * , u.region_name
FROM tree t
LEFT JOIN units u ON t.parent_id = u.region_id AND u.activity_id = 10066
WHERE t.entity_id = 8656
```

Answer (score 0):

It will be helpful if u show ur left join query.. anyway try this...

```
    SELECT t.entity_id, t.parent_id, t.length, u.region_name from tree t
    left join units u on t.parent_id = u.region_id and u.activity_id =10066
    WHERE t.entity_id = 8656
```